Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline) check rootdelay= did the system wait long enough and missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls ;dev)
Last Sunday I faced another issue in BusyBox initramfs, when I suspended my machine I wasn't able to come back to the login screen facing this screen:

I began desperately to press the power on button until my screen quit staying blank and after one or two minutes my screen turned on and I faced this screen below:

I searched many tutorials and videos around the net but no one has a detailed explanation about how to solve this problem. There is one where it suggests the user change the RAID operation to NVMe (I have tried to do that at the BIOS but the issue persisted and when I restarted the machine it returned with RAID enabled).
Also, I have tried to repair my boot loader from this site at Live USB: https://support.system76.com/articles/bootloader/ (My OS still is a Pop!_OS), from these commands below:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)

And again the issue persists.
Now I am using Pop!_OS in a different kernel and looking for a solution for that damaged kernel which I was using in case of any emergency. Is there any alternative solution for that? Also, I am using Windows in dual boot.
